# Is it correct to map a domain entity from within the controller (presentation layer)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design, separation-of-concerns

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2015 where I separate the DDD layers as projects. When I need to send data from the presentation layer (MVC 5) to the application layer (class library) I usually use:

**Application Service**

```
public interface IFooAppService
{
    void AddNew(string name, DateTime birthday);
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddNew(FooViewModel viewModel)
{
    FooAppService.AddNew(viewModel.Name, viewModel.birthday);
}
```

When I have a domain entity class with many properties and child entities, the application service method signature becomes too long. Considering DDD and separation of concerns, is it correct to map the `FooViewModel` class to the `Foo` domain entity right from the MVC Controller in this case? Such implementation would be:

**Application Service**

```
public interface IFooAppService
{
    void AddNew(Foo foo);
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddNew(FooViewModel viewModel)
{
    Foo foo = FooMapper.Map(viewModel);
    FooAppService.AddNew(Foo);
}
```

Comment: Of course. Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: I think it depends on the object. If the domain model mirrors your view model completely, there's no issue with it.  Transformation will need to happen either way.  But I wouldn't bleed unnecessary domain implementation into the view model just to make the mapping work.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - That's exactly my question. If I map the domain entity in the presentation layer, I feel that I'm leaking domain details into that layer, as MutantNinjaCodeMonkey pointed out. But if I pass all data as method parameters, I end up with a huge method signature. My goal is to find the best way to avoid that.

Comment: To anyone down voting this, please share your thoughts on how can I improve it, so I can fix it. So far, I think it is a valid concern that I have and others also may have in the future.

Comment: Generally, I avoid large method signatures by encapsulating the needed data into a dto-like value object, and follow the assembler pattern to do the mapping.  Most of my solutions have a network boundary between various presentation layers and my services, so it works well.

Comment: The controller is responsible for the wiring between your view and your domain. It's perfectly reasonable for it to have knowledge of that domain. Abstraction for the sake of abstraction is folly.

Comment: Generally speaking, I agree with Chris (especially what he says about abstraction).  For most applications and situations it's fine to do so.  It depends what kind of boundaries exist in the MVC transaction (as the MVC pattern itself isn't solely a server-to-client UI pattern). DDD systems of significant size/scale have to accommodate a lot more than just moving data from server to the UI client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is it correct to map the FooViewModel class to the Foo domain entity
>   right from the MVC Controller in this case?

If you have an Application Service, I would say no. You bothered creating an additional Application layer so that the presentation layer can concentrate on doing UI stuff and not deal with the Domain directly. It seems weird to want to short circuit that just because the "method signature is too long".

Besides, the concept of Command from CQ(R)S can help you solve that parameter problem. Controller can call the application service passing it just a Command.

Answer (score 0):

**If what you have is a simple mapping from DTOs to entities, you're probably building an [anemic domain model](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html).**

You should either try to build a full-blown domain model using DDD or resort to a CRUD-style application. Both of them are useful depending on the nature of the application. DDD usually only makes sense for complex problem domains.